# how to install wget in kubernetes postgresql pod

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I want to install some extensions in PosgreSQL, this is the issue what I am trying to archive:https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/issues/346. Now I success enable the initial folder and the next step I want to add some initial shell script to install some extension before container start. I tried to run the command in kubernetes pod before put it into initial script. when I using this command in kubernetes postgresql pod to install wget:

```
apt-get install wget -y
```

shows error like this:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

then I tried to switch to the root of the pod container:

```
su -
```

it need password, I am using helm to install the postgresql:

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm install my-release bitnami/postgresql
```

what should I do to install wget in the pod? I have tried this: https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/faq/administration/use-sudo/

Comment: Bitnami containers are designed to not allow any sudo operations, so you won't be able to install wget in it. 
But if you can explain what you're trying to achieve by doing that ? There might be other ways

Comment: I have add what I am trying to do right now to make the question more clear. @Hazim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use initContainers in order to download a script and use it in the postgres container. The initContainer would contain `wget` and download your script and put it in a volume. You can then mount the volume in your postgres container and execute it from there

The values.yaml for that chart would look something like

```yaml
primary:
  initContainers:
    - name: do-something
      image: image-with-wget
      command: ['wget', 'https://myscript']
      volumeMounts:
        - name: postgres-scripts
          mountPath: /postgres/path/for/scripts
```

Instead `/postgres/path/for/scripts` add the actual path where postgres can read from, or configure postgres to read from such a path

Comment: the script may be very complex, I want to download postgresql plugin and compile it then I want to install and created extension. @Hazim it it possible to use this instructions? https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/issues/346

Comment: The initial script I already copied into the volumn that postgresql container can load but could not execute it because the user not root. @Hazim

Comment: I think the instructions in the link refer to a database script you want to run at startup and not a plugin or general script. 
If its a plugin, you want to load before postgres runs, you can probably create your own docker image based on the existing docker image. Install the plugin as user root  and then change the user back to non-root.

Comment: thank you for your advice, I am trying to build my own package from the bitnami base. @Hazim I found install plugin before the database container start is unacceptable, it is too slow.